# PHP Accessing Censored Websites with Curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I want to access censored web sites with curl I setup the proxy and tested it. It works. But it's not enter the censored websites.

It's entering https sites.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '192.241.129.11');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8118');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');


$url = 'https://www.wikipedia.com';
//$url = 'https://www.google.com';


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;
```

Comment: What's the current result (response)? Any HTTP error message?

Comment: No there is not message just blank screen.

Comment: Check your error logs for messages / up your error reporting. Also, you probably wanted to use the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option too if you wanted the data back?

Comment: yes I added these things it is working on normal sites but not working on censored sites

Comment: What's considered "censored" and where is the censoring happening? Using a local proxy won't change anything if the proxy (you indicated an IP starting with "192." which is a local IP) still has to travel through the censor. In other words, if you're behind a firewall or gateway that is blocking access to certain outside domains or IPs, then it's going to block your proxy when it performs those same requests. A proxy doesn't magically replace the functionality from the upstream components.

Answer (score 0):

wikipedia.com specifically blocks requests that has no User-Agent, fix that.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Santa1923/bot)");
```